# CakePHP element missing on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, cakephp, project

I've just setup an Ubuntu 18.04 server, installed Apache and PHP on it. I want to run a CakePHP project so I cloned the repo from GitLab into `/var/www/html/<project>`.

I've installed composer and then run `composer install` into above path. I've modified the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` with the right path for DocumentRoot (`/var/www/html/playgrounds/webroot`), enabled apache2 rewrite and then restarted the apache server.

When I tried to access the URL, I encounter this error:

http://prntscr.com/pgxe9u

*(Element files missing)*

All elements are there, nothing is missing. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Confused. If you install via composer, why you need to cloned repo from gitlab?

Comment: I've cloned the project from GitLab with git-clone - `composer install` is mandatory after this.

Answer (score 0):

Typo into my 'default.ctp' layout. Calling elements as `$this->element("pages/main-menu")`, changed it into `$this->element("Pages/main-menu")` fixed it.